# Skype, Gtalk, etc... app detection on iOS

Tags: ios, voip, skype

I need to add ability to call certain number/account in my iOS app.
But I need to detect what user have Skype or other voice/video app on phone to show them variants.
Can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype defines the `skype` URL scheme. Just check if the device can open a `skype` URL, eg: `skype://+447123456789` to call +447123456789.

You can check any app to see if they have a URL scheme defined by downloading the app, renaming the `.ipa` file to end in `.zip`, extracting it and opening the `Info.plist` contained in the resulting bundle. If the application has a URL scheme then you can at least check if the app exists and open it if it does. What data you can send to it is app specific though.

Example:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:@"skype://123..."])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"skype://123..."];
}
```

Comment: I realy can check scheme or application existence in my app??

Comment: Yes, see the example I have added above. The application needs to support it though (Skype does!)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you know, can android do the same thing?